# Confusions about the statement of Leray's theorem for spectral sequences

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, fiber-bundles, spectral-sequences

I am trying to understand more precisely some aspects of the statement of Leray's theorem on spectral sequences, as stated in Loring Tu's "Introduction to Equivariant Cohomology". The statement is this:

[image: Leray's Theorem Statement]

EDITED: From the comments, I understand that the spectral sequence doesn't have anything to do with $E$ directly and also that $GH^*(E) = \bigoplus\limits_{i = 1}^\infty D_i/ D_{i+1}$.

We have for each $p \in \mathbb{N}$ an $F_p := \bigoplus\limits_{i \geq p} \bigoplus\limits_{q\geq 0} E_2^{i,q}$. Part of the statement of the theorem is that $F_p = \bigoplus\limits_{i \geq p} \bigoplus\limits_{q\geq 0} \left( H^i(B) \otimes H^q(F) \right)$.

What I realised still confuses me is this:
How is the filtration $D_p$ is derived from $F_p$, and does it even have anything to do with Leray's theorem at all?

I am guessing it's not part of the theorem, but it's something to do with singular cohomology and fiber bundles in general, i.e. if we have a filtration on $\bigoplus\limits_{p, q \in \mathbb{N}} (H^p(B) \otimes H^q(F))$, then this somehow translates to one in $H^*(E)$. Intuitively it seems like this should be the case, at least, but I am not familiar with singular cohomology.

Comment: To be confirmed by someone who knows better than I do, but I’m pretty sure that $E$ has nothing to do (it’s just a topological space) with the $E^{p,q}_r$ (which are constructed from homology groups – at least they’re algebraic objects, abelian groups).

Comment: Yes, the notation $E_r^{p,q}$ is used for all spectral sequences and has nothing to do with $E$.

Comment: And I think the notation $GH^*(E)$ means "the graded object associated to the filtered object $H^*(E)$".

Comment: @Captain Lama, so $GH^*(E)$ is then the direct sum in my second question. So it depends on the filtration but that is just not contained in the notation used?